# Haskell Couldn't match type, that is given by signature

Tags: list, haskell, types

Okay hi guys, I am having a weird problem.

```
hist :: [Int] -> [Int]
hist x = (foldr (+) 0 x)
```

The code above does not work, because trying to compile I am getting the error, that expected type '[Int]' could not be matched with actual type 'Int'. I don't get that.

Fun Fact: when I delete the signature, the function works fine!
Does anybody know the fault?

Thank you!

Comment: `foldr (+) 0 :: Num a => [a] -> a`. When you omit the type signature, the correct type for `hist` is inferred. If you want to specify a concrete type, it should be `[Int] -> Int`.

Comment: Hint: what is the return type of `foldr (+) 0`? (You can ask GHCi if you're not sure.)

Answer (score 4):

The output of the `foldr (+) 0 x` will be an `Int`, not an `[Int]`. If you want a list, you can use `scanl`, but I guess, you still want `foldr`:

```
hist :: [Int] -> Int
hist = foldr (+) 0
```

I however strongly advise to make use of [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) which also calculates the sum, but on all types that are instances of `Num`, and for all `Foldable`s (and thus not only a list).